# Numbering one equation in aligned environment

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

I have the following code:

```
$\begin{aligned}[t] 
P\{X\in A\}&=\int_A\int_{-1}^1 f(x, y)dydx \\  
&=\int_A\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{4}dydx \\ 
&=\int_A\frac{1}{4}\times 2dx \\ 
&=\int_A\frac{1}{2}dx 
\end{aligned}$
```

I want to label the last line as (2). How do I do this?

Comment: Where should the tag go?  THe will be text after the environment, I suppose.

Comment: I want the number (2) to show after the last equation. I tried \hfill(2) but it doesn't work.

Comment: why `$\begin{aligned}` rather than `\begin{align}` ? inline math doesn't normally get equation numbers

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, how would I do it if I were to use \begin{align}?

Answer (score 4):

What you need is `split`. The number will be assigned automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!d} % for integrals

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:someprob}
\begin{split}
P\{X\in A\}
  &=\int_A\int_{-1}^1 f(x, y)\diff y \diff x \\
  &=\int_A\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{4}\diff y \diff x \\
  &=\int_A\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2\diff x \\ 
  &=\int_A\frac{1}{2}\diff x 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how I got the right spacing for the differential symbols. If you change your mind and prefer a vertically centered number, remove the `tbtags` option.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `[b]` option for `aligned` rather than the `[t]`. Also, as others mentioned `$`s are used for inline math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      
\begin{document}

Some text above the formula ...
\begin{equation}\label{eq:niceformula}
\begin{aligned}[b]
P\{X\in A\}
  &=\int_A\int_{-1}^1 f(x, y)dy\, dx \\
  &=\int_A\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{4} dy\, dx \\
  &=\int_A\frac{1}{4}\cdot 2 dx \\ 
  &=\int_A\frac{1}{2} dx 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Some other text below the formula ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty simple with `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.
\begin{align}
P\{X\in A\}&=\int_A\int_{-1}^1 f(x, y)dydx \notag\\
&=\int_A\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{4}dydx \notag \\
&=\int_A\frac{1}{4}\times 2dx \notag\\
&=\int_A\frac{1}{2}dx \tag{2}
\end{align}
Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$` is for inline math but normally you only number display math constructs

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

zz
\begin{equation}
  1=2
\end{equation}
zz
\begin{align}
P\{X\in A\}&=\int_A\int_{-1}^1 f(x, y)dydx \notag\\  
&=\int_A\int_{-1}^1\frac{1}{4}dydx \notag\\ 
&=\int_A\frac{1}{4}\times 2dx \notag\\ 
&=\int_A\frac{1}{2}dx 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```